# What sort of IP address is this 2601:646:200:bbf:1da4:d869:d0d4:d3ed and should I be concerned that it tried to log into one of my financial accounts?

Tags: networking, ip-address

I was notified this this IP address tried to log into one of my financial accounts.  What is this type of address and should I be concerned?  Any information on this address would be helpful.

2601:646:200:bbf:1da4:d869:d0d4:d3ed

Comment: It is an IPv6 address. Only you can tell if someone tried to get into your financial accounts without you logging on first.

Comment: It’s probably your own IPv6 address if it accessed your account when you accessed it

Comment: When people ask "did I get hacked" the answer is almost always no. In this case it is almost certainly no.

Answer (score 2):

> What is this type of address

It's an IPv6 address (specifically one belonging to Comcast). Many ISPs have started using IPv6 (alongside or even instead of IPv4) to alleviate the address shortage that IPv4 has.

> and should I be concerned?

Purely based on the address type, no. IPv6 has been around for a while and is not particularly unusual to see even for home connections.

If you're using Comcast, search for "what is my IP" websites and check what your own IPv6 address is, the compare the first half (the `2601:646:200:bbf:`). If they're identical, it probably was your own address.

Otherwise, you *might* need to be concerned.

Comment: For many people the IPv6 address of their internet connection at home will change frequently so even if it is a different IPv6 address it might be just your internet connection at home. If not, it is far more likely that you logged in via a different connection than that a hacker logged in. If they did your money would probably be gone.

Comment: I checked my IPv6 and it is not mine.  Is it possible to determine where this address is located - state or country?

Comment: Not accurately. The ISP that owns it (Comcast) only operates in a single country (USA), as far as I know. Traceroute (`tracert`) results show that internally it's routed towards SF Bay Area. Anything more than that can only be known by the ISP itself.

Comment: ok - this is helpful.  perhaps it is mine and nothing to worry about - ty